# Spring Security remember-me with mongodb and Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-security

I try to use Spring Security to protected my app. Login code is as follow

```
//get UserDetails ....
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

Now I want to make Spring Security remember the user login, but i want do it using my code.
Please show me how.

### Thanks!

I try to use a simple way. I use the TokenBasedRememberMeServices to do the remember me.

```
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailService"></property>
        <property name="key" value="myRememberMeKey"></property>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

And the  is

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                    login-page="/login.jsp"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp"/>
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
</http>
```

The userDetailService is

```
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Resource
    private UserDao userDaoImp; 
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userName);
        List<User>ulist = userDaoImp.find(user);
        if(ulist.size() == 1){
            return (UserDetails) (ulist.toArray())[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I login from the login page there is a cookie : SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE
But when I close the webbrowser and open it again, it still turn into the login page. And it set the SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE "".
Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Why aren't letting Spring Security do it for you? Why reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Because I want to make sure everything under my control.

Comment: So basically you don't want to use any framework or don't trust a framework. Then don't use the framework. Use it or leave it but don't work around it.